# Lie algebra: symmetric and exterior power of representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra, $V$ and $W$ are representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ we define  the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V \otimes W$ in the following way: $X \cdot (v \otimes w)=(X \cdot v) \otimes w+v \otimes (X \cdot w)$.
But how can we define the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $Sym^2V$ and $\Lambda^2V$?

Comment: Once you have an action on $V^{\otimes n}$, just perform the usual quotient constructions to get the symmetric and exterior powers. These are quotients as $\mathfrak{g}$-modules, essentially by functoriality.

Comment: And why the weights of the exterior power are pairwise distinct sums of weights of $V$?

Comment: Pick a basis of $V$ consisting of weight vectors and use it to construct a basis of the exterior power in the usual way.